# Redundacia de clases

Tags: c#

Tengo una consulta! .. El caso es que tengo varias clases relacionadas a entity F. y cada clase me hace lo mismo para cada objeto. Listar,guardar,modificar buscar ext. como puedo hacer para simplificarla en una sola clase. Gracias!

Comment: Has leído algo del `patrón repositorio`. Echa un ojo aquí. [Implementar el repositorio y unidad de patrones de trabajo en una aplicación de ASP.NET MVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

podrias tener procedimientos almacenados en tu BD y llamarlos desde clases generales dependiendo de tu objeto a modificar o traer.
Un ejemplo de como seria

```
    public static List<object> Consultar(object obj, string Procedimiento, string Dato)
    {
        List<object> objs = new List<object>(); DataTable dt = clsDb.Consultar(Procedimiento, Dato);
        Type Tipo = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] propiedades = Tipo.GetProperties(); int Long = propiedades.Length; int Index = 0; int Field = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            object[] objDato = new object[Long];
            Field = 0;
            foreach (var prop in propiedades) { objDato[Field] = row[prop.Name].ToString(); Field++; }
            objs.Add(objDato);
        }
        return objs;
    }
```

y un ejemplo de procedimiento almacenado en tu BD

```
create procedure [dbo].[spClientesMostrar] ( @Buscar varchar(50) = '' ) as
select * from TClientes where Cliente like '%' + @Buscar + '%' and Anulado = 0 order by Cliente
```

Si no me equiboco esto se llama 'Reflection', espero que te sirva :D

Comment: Gracias amigo ! voy a ver que sale. Ya que estas no sabes donde puede haber info sobre ese tema? pq cuando busco me salen otras cosas.